# More readable approach than nested if statements with timeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Im making an exercise timer. Im using React but I don't think thats important for my specific question.

The timer counts down every second. There are multiple sets (each set is a different exercise), and every set is repeated for each round.

My code below works but its starting to get hard to read. I also need to add rest periods after each set so if I continued with my current approach I would need even more if statements.

```
timer() {
    this.myTimer = setInterval(() => {
      // When the set time goes down to 0...
      if (this.state.setTimeRemaining === 0) {
        // Increment the set number
        this.setState({currentSet: this.state.currentSet + 1});
        // Reset the remaining time
        this.setState({setTimeRemaining: this.state.setLength + 1});
      }
      // When the last set in the round is passed...
      if (this.state.currentSet > this.state.noOfSets) {
        // Reset the set number
        this.setState({currentSet: 1});
        // Increment the round number
        this.setState({currentRound: this.state.currentRound + 1});
      }
      // If we've finished...
      if (this.state.currentRound > this.state.noOfRounds) {
        this.updateProgress('complete');
      }
      // Minus 1 second from the current set time
      this.setState({setTimeRemaining: this.state.setTimeRemaining - 1});
      if (this.state.progress === 'running') {
        // Update the timer bar's status
        this.updateTimerBar();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

What method is best suited to this situation? I could use a switch statement? Im using Babel so im able to use the latest JavaScript methods / syntax.

Comment: well.. 1 thing is that you can set multiple state inside 1 `this.setState()`. no need to separate them all

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids nesting. Im using returns to exit the block when a condition is matched. The error message at the end will tell me if no condition has been met.

```
 timer() {
    this.myTimer = setInterval(() => {

      // Not resting. Not at end of set
      if (this.state.resting === false && this.state.setTimeRemaining > 0) {
        // Negative increment set time
        this.setState({setTimeRemaining: this.state.setTimeRemaining - 1});
        return;
      }

      // Not resting. At end of set
      if (this.state.resting === false && this.state.setTimeRemaining === 0) {
        // Set resting state to true
        this.setState({resting: true});
        return;
      }

      // Resting. Not end of rest
      if (this.state.resting === true && this.state.restTimeRemaining > 0) {
        // Negative increment rest time
        this.setState({restTimeRemaining: this.state.restTimeRemaining - 1});
        return;
      }

      // Resting. At end of rest. Not at last set in round
      if (this.state.resting === true && this.state.restTimeRemaining === 0
        && this.state.currentSet < this.state.noOfSets) {
        this.setState({
          currentSet: this.state.currentSet + 1,    // Increment the current set no
          setTimeRemaining: this.state.setLength,   // Reset the set time remaining
          restTimeRemaining: this.state.restLength, // Reset the rest time remaining
          resting: false                            // Turn off resting flag
        });
        return;
      }

      // Resting. At end of rest. Reached last set in round. Not last round in session
      if (this.state.resting === true && this.state.restTimeRemaining === 0
        && this.state.currentSet === this.state.noOfSets
        && this.state.currentRound < this.state.noOfRounds) {
        this.setState({
          currentRound: this.state.currentRound + 1, // Increment hte round no
          currentSet: 1,                             // Reset the set no
          setTimeRemaining: this.state.setLength,    // Reset the set time remaining
          restTimeRemaining: this.state.restLength,  // Reset the rest time remaining
          resting: false                             // Turn off resting flag
        });
        return;
      }

      // Resting. At end of rest. Reached last set in round. Reached last round in session
      if (this.state.resting === true && this.state.restTimeRemaining === 0
        && this.state.currentSet === this.state.noOfSets
        && this.state.currentRound === this.state.noOfRounds) {
        this.updateProgress('complete'); // We've finished the session 
        return;
      }

      // This console message should never be reached
      console.error('Timer error - a condition was not returned');
    }, 1000);
  }
```